# android gps location listener not working in some device

Tags: android, gps

I have written a GPS code using location listener for capturing latitude and longitude of a current location  and it is working fine for most  of my devices.
But some  devices( particularly Samsung ) is not able to load this latitude longitude from location listener.
This is the code i have used continuously changing latitude and longitude.

```
    public class MyLocationListner implements LocationListener {


            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String getLatitude = "" + location.getLatitude();
            String getLongitude = "" + location.getLongitude();


            double x = location.getLatitude();
            double y = location.getLongitude();
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
    }
```

To call above location listener i am using below piece of code in my activity.

*emphasized text*

```
{LocationManager location_manager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
             LocationListener listner = new MyLocationListner();
             location_manager.requestLocationUpdates(
             LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listner);
}
```

Please give the solution why it is not working.

Thanks in advance